# How to make plugin Worpress self-deactivated?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Good day, I need a plugin to be self-deactivated once the mail is sent to the site owner. However, when I run on local machine the plugins still active in my admin panel.
My code :

```
if(count($result) == 0){
    // Send the mail
    send_to_mail();       
    // self deactivation of this plugin
    add_action( 'init', 'deactivate_cronjob_plugin' );
}

// deactivate the plugin
function deactivate_cronjob_plugin(){
    if ( is_plugin_active('myPlugin/cron_job.php') ) {
        deactivate_plugins('myPlugin/cron_job.php', true);    
    }
}
```

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.6, I'm glad if there's any help. Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: You need to find the main files base -> `deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); ` if it is the same file - else find it. furthermore - if this need to run after something - then you can't add it as an init function - but you might be able to just call your function instead of using an action

Comment: try to use this add_action('update_option_active_plugins', 'deactivate_cronjob_plugin');

Comment: Hi, thank you for both help but it's not working for both cases. Looks like the function is not firing.

Answer (score 1):

You need the hole path to the plugin file, like

```
deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
```

Also the small note that the function `is_plugin_active` is not necessary. The deactivation works only, if the plugin is active.